# Creating custom Menu for custom theme

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I want to create a custom menu for my theme. The default menu architecture created by wordpress `wp_nav_menu()` function is made by `<ul>` `<li>` tags. But my custom Menu architecture is:

```
<body>
  <div class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
    <a href="#" class="item">
      1
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="item">
      2
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="item">
      3
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    <!-- Site content !-->
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I create such a menu for my custom theme?

I tried using custom `walker` function... but I am not able to understand, how does the function work.

Comment: Is there a reason the `ul` and `li` tags wont work?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the container and ul tag like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
   'container' => '',
   'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
) ); ?>
```

Now you can see an architecture like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">item</a>
</li>
```

And i think you could adjust your stylesheet to adapt "li" tag.

Hope it helps.